# Does Amazon AWS cost reset every month

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does Amazon price for GB storage reset every month? Say in January I used 1000GB of storage and pay it off for $40. Do I get charged $40 in February even if I don’t use any storage or do I pay $0 in February? Basically is AWS storage price static or does it reset every month?

Comment: Are you using RDS with EBS or EC2's with EBS?

Comment: you will be charged if you are using the storage every day. you will not be charged if you delete the storage and any snapshots that were created. you could check the costs under Cost Explorer per day

Comment: @Sri So it’s static?

Comment: @RossBush not sure. I just upload video files to my s3 bucket and display them on my website.

Comment: If you left a file in S3, then you will still be charged for it, as it's still using space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 is [charged](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) on two main dimensions:

- **Storage:** A charge for the amount of data kept in Amazon S3, charged per GB per month
- **Requests:** A charge for the number of requests made to S3, charged per 1000 requests

If you keep 1000GB of data in Amazon S3 as **Standard storage** charged as `$0.023 per GB`, then you would be charged `1000 x $0.023 = $23` for that month of storage.

If you kept 1000GB of data in Amazon S3 for **half a month**, then it would be only **half that cost**.

Think of it like **parking your car in a parking garage** -- they charge you for every hour that you keep your car parked. However, if your car isn't parked in the garage, then they don't charge you anything.